# ERRSOLVE : Unable to resolve dependacny

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, web-development-server

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving: chat-app@0.1.0 npm ERR!
> Found: react@18.2.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!
> react@"^18.2.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not
> resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from
> @material-ui/core@4.12.4

I am getting this error while installing material ui through npm. Please help me with  the installation procedure of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the command below:

```
npm install @material-ui/core --force
```

Or use legacy-peer-deps

```
npm install @material-ui/core --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

One more issue may be your React version or node js version.If your node version is 12 try upgrading to version 16.You can do it using [NVM](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/).Using it you can manage multiple node versions in one machine.After installations use following command to use specific node version:

```
nvm use vA.B.C
```

One more solution is to clean cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are installing in the folder that contains your package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Add --legacy-peer-deps like this:
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps